# Sending files over ftp using Apache Camel

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, file-transfer

I've been trying to copy a file from the local directory to a remote directory. The problem is I don't know how to specify the address of the destination which is another computer. Can someone please show an example of ftp URL with ip address. It would be helpful if the URL also include user name, password, port and a specific path .Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, read the section **URI format** of ftp Camel manual
(http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html).

According to Camel documentation:

**URI format**

```
ftp://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
sftp://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
ftps://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
```

Just replace the *hostname* by remote IP.

URL also can include *password* :

```
ftp://user:password@192.168.10.20:21/dir/subdir
```

or you can define *user* and *password* in options:

```
ftp://192.168.10.20:21/dir/subdir?user=user&password=password
```

Comment: I tried this already. There doesn't seem to be any bug but the destination is simply not receiving the file. I'm trying to send it to another computer on the same network. Could you show me an example of the URL if my destination directory is E://test/inbox on the other computer. Are the user name and password the same as the credentials required for logging in to the computer?

Comment: @Milan Do you use ftp or smb? This path ( E://test/inbox ) does not matter, because you can map this directory to a logical directory with any name. It depends on the settings of your ftp server.

Comment: I use ftp.And I don't know about manually setting up the ftp server.If i have to send files to another computer,is there some sort of configuration needed for the other computer

Comment: @Milan If it is a foreign ftp server, then you need to know the directory and you have to specify it in the URL.
If this is your test ftp server you can configure the directories as you need. Here is an example of the configuration directories on my server Filezilla http://prntscr.com/g5bfm4 C:\install will be root dir, all install subdirectory will be ftp subdirirectory. URL will be ftp://free:free@127.0.0.1:21/xml (xml is subdir of install dir) or just ftp://free:free@127.0.0.1:21/ for accessing to с:\install dir

Comment: Thank you Alexey .It helped!